# Are "extended" variants of a spell considered a separate spell for the purpose of purchase?

Tags: spells, shadowrun-sr5

Are "extended" versions of spells considered separate items for the purpose of purchasing spells?

For example the spell "Detect enemies" has a variant "Detect enemies, extended", if I were to purchase "Detect enemies", do I also get "Detect enemies, extended" for the same cost or must I purchase "Detect enemies, extended" separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## They are separate spells

If you look at the description of how Detection spells work, you get the following...

> The standard range of the sense a Detection spell grants is the spell’s Force x caster’s Magic in meters as a radius from the target of the spell. Extended-range  detection spells have a Force x Magic x 10 meter range.

SR5 CRB, p285

If the normal version and Extended version were the same spell, but cast in different 'modes,' then it wouldn't be referring to them as two distinct types of Spell. They wouldn't be listed as two distinct types of spell. Instead, you'd get a rule that said something like "Or, if you choose to increase the Drain of the spell by [X], you may multiple the range of the spell by 10."

Additionally, look at how they are formatted in the books...it's the exact same way that other 'related' spells are laid out.

Detect Life and Detect Life [Extended] are formatted the exact same way (Name and list of traits for each 'spell,' with a single paragraph describing the set beneath them) as Punch, Clout, and Blast are.

Given the phrasing of the description of how Detection Spell Ranges work, given the identical formatting, and given the lack of any rules calling out an exception--it's fairly clear that normal-range detection spells and extended-range detection spells are distinct spells that much be learned separately.